# Sql Server And Very Hot CPU % of Total Wait Time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have recently started monitoring a production database with transactional replication. The CPU % of Total Wait time = %**93.00**.

This is horrible. I confirmed all 8 processors are being utilized. This database has been in production for six years, so I am wondering is the 93 percent reporting 93% of all processors or is there something I am missing?

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the query you are using to get this number?

Comment: No, taskmanager shows the cpu to be very low.

Comment: Hi Edward, thats the thing. When I execute.....SELECT 
 CPU_Pressure=SUM(signal_wait_time_ms) * 100 / SUM(wait_time_ms),
 CPU_Wait=SUM(signal_wait_time_ms),
    CPU_ResourceWait=SUM(wait_time_ms - signal_wait_time_ms),
    CPU_TotalWait=SUM(wait_time_ms)
FROM   
 SYS.DM_OS_WAIT_STATS....I get 19 for CPU pressure. I am creating a baseline in the data collector and it is reporting that the CPU is 98% of all waits.

Comment: I added a capture from the baseline testing. The number highlighted above should be much lower.

Comment: Do you get a similar percentage from running the query here? http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Wait-statistics-or-please-tell-me-where-it-hurts.aspx

Comment: Might want to see if Jonathan Kehayias's comment here applies to your situation (similar to Max Vernon's comment above): http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldatabaseengine/thread/f2bbf00b-04e7-450d-bae5-a6880fc04a36

Comment: +1 for you James. I'm curious to see what the waitstat query will return. @Ltn one comment to your query your using. If you don't filter out all the sleeping waitstats, you might get a skewed result as well. You'll add a lot of wait stats with 0 signal wait time, effectively lowering your total signal_wait_time when it should not. Use Paul's query that James hinted to see what I mean. You'll notice that a lot is filter out and even then, some wiat types will cumulate a lot of signal_wait_time while others don't

Comment: I think James pointed to the answer. The data collector seems to lump more than expected into the "CPU category" of % of total waits. Using Jame's sqlskill.com query things seem more rational, with CXPACKET being the highest at 32%. I will put the comment from James as the solution :)

Comment: Might be any single thread query/scheduled job at backend might be consuming so much cpu

Answer (score 1):

SOS_SCHEDULER_YEILD is not the cause, it's a side effect. It just means that something else is burning the cycles. In your graph, the second is LOGGING; this makes sense considering you are running replication. Based on my prior experience, you are probably experiencing log reader. This is typical; [you can reduce your PollingInterval and increase CommitBatchSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151762.aspx)

Use [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), sort by highest CPU usage process, must be sqlservr. Right click on sqlsrvr, go to properties, click on threads tab, sort by highest CPU column to see the highest cpu consuming thread. Note the thread id(s) down. Execute the below statement to see what is query is using the most CPU

```
select r.session_id, st.text, qp.query_plan from sys.dm_os_threads as ot join sys.dm_os_tasks as t on t.worker_address=ot.worker_address join sys.dm_exec_requests as r on t.session_id=r.session_id cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) as st cross apply sys.dm_exec_query_plan(r.plan_handle) as qp where os_thread_id=<from process explorer high CPU thread>
```